# How to fix "...PlaceHistoryMapperWithFactory cannot be implemented more than once..."

Tags: java, gwt

i just tried PlaceHistoryMapperWithFactory as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089964/places-that-share-all-but-prefix-or-how-to-use-placehistorymapperwithfactory) . So my AppPlaceHistoryMapper looks like that:

```
    @WithTokenizers({ InfoPlace.Tokenizer.class, LogPlace.Tokenizer.class })
public interface AppPlaceHistoryMapper extends PlaceHistoryMapperWithFactory<TokenizerFactory> {

}
```

i also changed teh gin module:

```
bind(PlaceHistoryMapperWithFactory.class).to(AppPlaceHistoryMapper.class);
```

but i won't gwt-compile. i get

```
[INFO] Compiling module de.stalabw.zensus2011.adb.AuswertungsDB
[INFO]    Scanning for additional dependencies: ...ClientInjectorImpl.java
[INFO]       Adding '57' new generated units
[INFO]          Validating newly compiled units
[INFO]             Ignored 1 unit with compilation errors in first pass.
[INFO] Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
[INFO]    [ERROR] Errors in '...PlaceHistoryMapperWithFactoryImpl.java'
[INFO]       [ERROR] Line 10:  The interface PlaceHistoryMapperWithFactory cannot be implemented more than once with different arguments: PlaceHistory
MapperWithFactory<Void> and PlaceHistoryMapperWithFactory
[INFO]    [ERROR] Cannot proceed due to previous errors
```

i just fixed the same error in my unit tests. there i have an Mock-Implementation. i just changed

```
public class PlaceHistoryMapperMock extends AbstractPlaceHistoryMapper<void> implements
AppPlaceHistoryMapper
```

to

```
public class PlaceHistoryMapperMock extends AbstractPlaceHistoryMapper<TokenizerFactory> implements
AppPlaceHistoryMapper
```

and the error was gone. but how to fix it for my "real" code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that you have a `GWT.create(PlaceHistoryMapperWithFactory.class)` somewhere in the code (possibly generated by GIN), for which the generator attemps to generate a `PlaceHistoryMapperWithFactoryImpl` class (that class name is symptomatic) that implements both `PlaceHistoryMapperWithFactory` (that's passed to `GWT.create()`) and `PlaceHistoryMapperWithFactory<Void>` (because the generated class extends `AbstractPlaceHistoryMapper<Void>`).

It really depends how your dependency on `PlaceHistoryMapperWithFactory` is declared in your code.

IMO, you should probably have a dependency on `PlaceHistoryMapper` in your code, rather than some `PlaceHistoryMapperWithFactory`. In case you need that dependency (because that's where you call `setFactory`), you should have a dependency on the parameterized type `PlaceHistoryMapperWithFactory<TokenizerFactory>`, which has to be mapped in GIN using a `TypeLiteral`:

```
bind(new TypeLiteral<PlaceHistoryMapperWithFactory<TokenizerFactory>>() {}).to(AppPlaceHistoryMapper.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

ok i got it. the problem is

```
bind(PlaceHistoryMapperWithFactory.class).to(AppPlaceHistoryMapper.class);
```

since there is no PlaceHistoryMapperWithFactory.class this will bind the wrong implementation. my solution is a provider:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public final PlaceHistoryMapperWithFactory<TokenizerFactory> getPlaceHistoryMapper(AppPlaceHistoryMapper hm) {
    return hm;
}
```

that seems to work.